# Need SQL assistance, Column A and B are distinct, but column c has multiple values. Need to add column D for second distinct value when present

Tags: sql, tablesorter

I need help isolating multiple entries in order.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100a | 1000 | ABC |
| 100a | 1000 | DEF |
| 200b | 2000 | GHI |
| 300c | 3000 | JKL |
| 300c | 3000 | MNO |

There are duplicates in Column A (which has a 1:1 relationship to column b).  However, they have a 1:many with column C.  Column C will always be unique.

I need to create a report that returns:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1000 | ABC | DEF |
| 200 | 2000 | GHI |  |
| 300 | 3000 | JKL | MNO |

Any help?  I am pretty new to SQL so this is giving me a lot of trouble figuring it out.

I am at a loss where to start.  I tried to declare a variable, but not sure where to start with it.

Comment: Hi - you probably need to research using a PIVOT statement

Comment: Which database vendor is used?

Comment: How do I tell the difference?  I dont think it is T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If it's no more than 2 values in `Column C` for `Column A` + `Column B` key, then a query below would work. It will not work for 3 or more values

```
SELECT 
  Column_A, 
  Column_B, 
  MIN(Column_C) AS "Column C", 
  CASE WHEN MIN(Column_C) <> MAX(Column_C) 
     THEN MAX(Column_C)
     ELSE ''
  END AS "Column D"
FROM some_table
GROUP BY Column_A, Column_B
```

| Column_A | Column_B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100a | 1000 | ABC | DEF |
| 200b | 2000 | GHI |  |
| 300c | 3000 | JKL | MNO |

(live demo: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fzuqMbjz) )